# Reading ACS71020 over I2C gives choppy and inaccurate data

Tags: arduino, ac, i2c, attiny

I am programming ATtiny414 which read current, power and detect zero-crossing. For Test, I connect 220V 72W light bulb but I can't read accurate value. Also I observe zero-crossing pin and it is irregular. Here is power on and power off data and my code. How can I obtain values like 220V 72W and 0,32A. I want to make some operation like if current is over X values do something etc.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define kNOERROR 0
#define kREADERROR 1
#define kWRITEERROR 2
//const uint8_t WRITE = 0x00;
const uint8_t READ = 0x80;
//const uint8_t COMMAND_MASK = 0x80;
//const uint8_t ADDRESS_MASK = 0x7F;
unsigned long nextTime;
bool ledOn = false;
bool UseI2C = false;
// Setup the demo board.
void setup()
{

  // Initialize serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Turn on the pullup so the determination of communication protocol can be made.
  PORTB.PIN0CTRL = PIN3_bm; // Enables internal pull-up of SCL
  PORTB.PIN1CTRL = PIN3_bm; // Enables internal pull-up of SDA

  PORTA.DIRSET = PIN3_bm; // P_ON pin (PA3) as a output
                          // PA1 and PA2 is default input
  PORTA.OUTSET = PIN3_bm; // Initiaally Power OFF
  delay(50); // Wait for the pullup to take affect
  UseI2C = true;
  
  if (UseI2C)
  {
    // Initialize I2C
    Wire.begin();
    Wire.setClock(200000);
  }

  Write(0x2F, 0x4F70656E); // Unlock device
  //Write(0x1B, 0x00340000); // Set gain 4.5x and iavg select current
  //Write(0x1C, 0x00000820); // Set gain rms_avg_1 = 64
  
  // If the Arduino has built in USB, keep the next line
  // in to wait for the Serial to initialize
  while (!Serial);
  if (UseI2C)
  {
  Serial.println(" Using I2C version of ACS71020 ");
  }

  PORTA.DIRSET = PIN4_bm; // Set the A and B to trigger transmitter mode of RS485
  PORTA.OUTSET = PIN4_bm;
  
  nextTime = millis();
  
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:  
  uint32_t vrms_irms;
uint32_t vrms;
uint32_t irms;
uint32_t pactive;
uint32_t paparent;
uint32_t pimag;
uint32_t pfactor;
uint32_t numptsout;
uint32_t vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec;
uint32_t vrmsavgonesec;
uint32_t irmsavgonesec;
uint32_t vrmsavgonemin_irmsavgonemin;
uint32_t vrmsavgonemin;
uint32_t irmsavgonemin;
uint32_t pactavgonesec;
uint32_t pactavgonemin;
uint32_t vcodes;
uint32_t icodes;
uint32_t pinstant;
uint32_t flags;

  // Every 1/2 second, toggle the state of the LED and read the ACS71020
  if (nextTime < millis())
  {
    PORTA.OUTCLR = PIN3_bm;  
    Read(0x20, vrms_irms);
    Read(0x21, pactive);
    Read(0x22, paparent);
    Read(0x23, pimag);
    Read(0x24, pfactor);
    Read(0x25, numptsout);
    Read(0x26, vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec);
    Read(0x27, vrmsavgonemin_irmsavgonemin);
    Read(0x28, pactavgonesec);
    Read(0x29, pactavgonemin);
    Read(0x2A, vcodes);
    Read(0x2B, icodes);
    Read(0x2C, pinstant);
    Read(0x2D, flags);
        
    vrms = vrms_irms & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Vrms: ");
    Serial.print(vrms);
    Serial.print("\r\n");
    
    irms = (vrms_irms >> 16) & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Irms: ");
    Serial.print(irms);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    pactive = pactive & 0x1FFFF;
    Serial.print(" Pactive: ");
    Serial.print(pactive);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    paparent = paparent & 0xFFFF;
    Serial.print(" Paparent: ");
    Serial.print(paparent);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    vrmsavgonesec = vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Vrmsavgonesect: ");
    Serial.print(vrmsavgonesec);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    irmsavgonesec = (vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec >> 16) & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Irmsavgonesec: ");
    Serial.print(irmsavgonesec);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    nextTime = millis() + 1500L;
    }
}
/*
* Read a register
*
* address - the address to be written
* value - the value that was read
* returns - the error (0 otherwise)
*/
uint16_t Read(uint8_t address, uint32_t& value)
{
  uint32_t buf;
  uint16_t results = kNOERROR;
  uint8_t a,b,c,d;
  if (UseI2C)
  {
    Wire.beginTransmission(127); // 127 ACS adress
    Wire.write(address);
    results = Wire.endTransmission();
    if (results == kNOERROR)
    {
      
      Wire.requestFrom(127, 4);
      delay(5);      
      size_t actually_read = Wire.readBytes((uint8_t*)&buf, 4);
      value = buf;
      
    }
  }
  
  return results;
}


/*
* Write a register
*
* address - the address to be written
* value - the value to be written
* returns - the error (0 otherwise)
*/
uint32_t Write(uint8_t address, uint32_t value)
{
  uint8_t results = kNOERROR;
  if (UseI2C)
  {
    Wire.beginTransmission(127); // 127 ACS adress
    // Send the address then the value (least significant byte first)
    Wire.write(address);
    Wire.write(value);
    Wire.write(value >> 8);
    Wire.write(value >> 16);
    Wire.write(value >> 24);
    results = Wire.endTransmission();
  }
  
  if (address < 0x10)
  {
    delay(30); // If writing to EEPROM delay 30 ms
  }
  return results;
}
```

[image: Power Off Values]

Power Off Values

[image: Power On Values]

Power On Values

Comment: Change uint16_t Read(uint8_t address, uint32_t& value) to uint16_t Read(uint8_t address, uint32_t* value) and value = buf to **value = buf or Wire.readBytes((uint8_t*)&buf, 4) to Wire.readBytes((uint8_t*)&value, 4) and discard local stack buffer. Also move your local field (the u32 declarations) out of loop(void) and make them global and static volatile.

Comment: The chip data are fixed point floats, it would be nice to convert them. The value of Pactive is a signed value and the sign bit is set. This produces the big values if you show it as unsigned int. The current flow direction is reverse. if bit 16 is set, then OR it with 0xFFFF0000 and cast it as int32_t. There are other problems, I currently have no explanation. Probably they disappear if you decode them properly.

Comment: Getting pactive would be nice but it is not vital. My priorities are current and voltage and detecting zero-crossing. This chip is 90A, it means 65536 value of rms (because it is 16-bit) corresponds to 90A. I try to set gain 4.5x which means now 65536 corresponds to 20A. I try to calculate what 540 value corresponds but it is not give me a 0.30A.

Answer (score -1):

Changed your snippet.
Did include minimal comments.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define kNOERROR 0
#define kREADERROR 1
#define kWRITEERROR 2
//const uint8_t WRITE = 0x00;
const uint8_t READ = 0x80;
//const uint8_t COMMAND_MASK = 0x80;
//const uint8_t ADDRESS_MASK = 0x7F;
unsigned long nextTime;
bool ledOn = false;
bool UseI2C = false;

/* All fields in a single struct */
/* Is more readable - declare as packed */
typedef struct  __attribute__((packed)){  
    uint32_t vrms_irms;
    uint32_t vrms;
    uint32_t irms;
    uint32_t pactive;
    uint32_t paparent;
    uint32_t pimag;
    uint32_t pfactor;
    uint32_t numptsout;
    uint32_t vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec;
    uint32_t vrmsavgonesec;
    uint32_t irmsavgonesec;
    uint32_t vrmsavgonemin_irmsavgonemin;
    uint32_t vrmsavgonemin;
    uint32_t irmsavgonemin;
    uint32_t pactavgonesec;
    uint32_t pactavgonemin;
    uint32_t vcodes;
    uint32_t icodes;
    uint32_t pinstant;
    uint32_t flags;
} SensorData_t;

/* Global not local storage */
/* ALso make it volatile out of habbit */
 volatile SensorData_t SensorData;


// Setup the demo board.
void setup()
{

  // Initialize serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Turn on the pullup so the determination of communication protocol can be made.
  PORTB.PIN0CTRL = PIN3_bm; // Enables internal pull-up of SCL
  PORTB.PIN1CTRL = PIN3_bm; // Enables internal pull-up of SDA

  PORTA.DIRSET = PIN3_bm; // P_ON pin (PA3) as a output
                          // PA1 and PA2 is default input
  PORTA.OUTSET = PIN3_bm; // Initiaally Power OFF
  delay(50); // Wait for the pullup to take affect
  UseI2C = true;
  
  if (UseI2C)
  {
    // Initialize I2C
    Wire.begin();
    Wire.setClock(200000);
  }

  Write(0x2F, 0x4F70656E); // Unlock device
  //Write(0x1B, 0x00340000); // Set gain 4.5x and iavg select current
  //Write(0x1C, 0x00000820); // Set gain rms_avg_1 = 64
  
  // If the Arduino has built in USB, keep the next line
  // in to wait for the Serial to initialize
  while (!Serial);
  if (UseI2C)
  {
  Serial.println(" Using I2C version of ACS71020 ");
  }

  PORTA.DIRSET = PIN4_bm; // Set the A and B to trigger transmitter mode of RS485
  PORTA.OUTSET = PIN4_bm;
  
  nextTime = millis();
  
}
void loop() {

  // Every 1/2 second, toggle the state of the LED and read the ACS71020
  if (nextTime < millis())
  {
    /* Makes main() more readable */
    ReadData(&SensorData);
    
    SensorData.vrms = SensorData.vrms_irms & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Vrms: ");
    Serial.print(SensorData.vrms);
    Serial.print("\r\n");
    
    SensorData.irms = (SensorData.vrms_irms >> 16) & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Irms: ");
    Serial.print(SensorData.irms);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    SensorData.pactive = SensorData.pactive & 0x1FFFF;
    Serial.print(" Pactive: ");
    Serial.print(SensorData.pactive);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    SensorData.paparent = SensorData.paparent & 0xFFFF;
    Serial.print(" Paparent: ");
    Serial.print(SensorData.paparent);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    SensorData.vrmsavgonesec = SensorData.vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Vrmsavgonesect: ");
    Serial.print(SensorData.vrmsavgonesec);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    SensorData.irmsavgonesec = (SensorData.vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec >> 16) & 0x7FFF;
    Serial.print(" Irmsavgonesec: ");
    Serial.print(SensorData.irmsavgonesec);
    Serial.print("\r\n");

    nextTime = millis() + 1500L;
    }
}

/*
* Reads the entire device 
*/
void ReadData(volatile SensorData_t *dat){
    PORTA.OUTCLR = PIN3_bm;  
    Read(0x20, &dat->vrms_irms);
    Read(0x21, &dat->pactive);
    Read(0x22, &dat->paparent);
    Read(0x23, &dat->pimag);
    Read(0x24, &dat->pfactor);
    Read(0x25, &dat->numptsout);
    Read(0x26, &dat->vrmsavgonesec_irmsavgonesec);
    Read(0x27, &dat->vrmsavgonemin_irmsavgonemin);
    Read(0x28, &dat->pactavgonesec);
    Read(0x29, &dat->pactavgonemin);
    Read(0x2A, &dat->vcodes);
    Read(0x2B, &dat->icodes);
    Read(0x2C, &dat->pinstant);
    Read(0x2D, &dat->flags);
}

/*
* Read a register
*
* address - the address to be written
* value - the value that was read
* returns - the error (0 otherwise)
*/
uint16_t Read(uint8_t address, volatile uint32_t* value)
{
  uint16_t results = kNOERROR;
  if (UseI2C)
  {
    Wire.beginTransmission(127); // 127 ACS adress
    Wire.write(address);
    results = Wire.endTransmission();
    if (results == kNOERROR)
    {
      
      Wire.requestFrom(127, 4);
      delay(5);   /* Required ? */   
      size_t actually_read = Wire.readBytes((uint8_t*)&value, 4);
      
    }
  }
  
  return results;
}


/*
* Write a register
*
* address - the address to be written
* value - the value to be written
* returns - the error (0 otherwise)
*/
uint32_t Write(uint8_t address, uint32_t value)
{
  uint8_t results = kNOERROR;
  if (UseI2C)
  {
    Wire.beginTransmission(127); // 127 ACS adress
    // Send the address then the value (least significant byte first)
    Wire.write(address);
    Wire.write(value);
    Wire.write(value >> 8);
    Wire.write(value >> 16);
    Wire.write(value >> 24);
    results = Wire.endTransmission();
  }
  
  if (address < 0x10)
  {
    delay(30); // If writing to EEPROM delay 30 ms
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It make sense about clean code. But now every value is 0

Comment: Did just edit the code. Maybe try again?

Comment: Can you at least *say* what you think the error is??  As it stands, even if the code edit you made is 100% correct, the answer has little value.